# Adding button to the opposite side of entry-title

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook

Im trying to add a button to the opposite side of entry-title specific page of wordpress customizr theme. 
Here's my ref. https://presscustomizr.com/customizr/hooks-api/ theme page but I really dont know how to do.
I tried a php functions but it doesnt work.
Need some help please.

```
add_action ('__before_archive_title', 'button_beside_title');

function button_beside_title() {
if ( !is_page( array( '3154' ) ) ){
    echo 'Text Example';
}}
```

Comment: Using ::before cannot use html elements as <button> but only 'text'    `' h1.entry-title::after {
 content: 'text';
 right: 80px;
 text-align: ;
 position: absolute;
}'`

Comment: I also tried to add some text next to the tile but is wrong.

`function content_next_title() {
if ( !is_page( '3154' ) ) ){
 echo 'test';
}}
add_filter ('tc_content_title_tag', 'content_next_title');`